# Syntax error: invalid syntax every time I put an array as an argument to __init__

Tags: python, arrays, init

For example, this method:

```
import pygame
import mapas

class ContenedoresPorCapa():

    def __init__(self, layers[]):
        self.mapasCapas = len(self.mapas.capas)
        for i in range(mapasCapas):
            return layers[i]
```

Comment: That's Java's syntax IIRC.

Comment: no it's not :) and even if it were, it'd be fairer to say it's C or C++ syntax.

Comment: usually when you ask for help because of an error, it's best to include the actual error so we don't waste time trying to figure out which problem to solve.

Comment: @user3571326 I see you don't like accepting any of the answers you are given — but you should start doing that.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `[]` in the parameter list:

```
import pygame
import mapas

class ContenedoresPorCapa:
    def __init__(self, layers):
        self.mapasCapas = len(self.mapas.capas)
        for i in range(mapasCapas):
            return layers[i]
```

Also, note that `return`ing values from `__init__` methods of classes (constructors) is meaningless (and will produce a runtime `TypeError`, as Aशwini चhaudhary kindly pointed out).

Also the `()` at the end of the class definition is redundant.

Furthermore, this for loop will only iterate once and then return immediately:

```
for i in range(mapasCapas):
    return layers[i]
```

Unless you describe what your goal is, it seems impossible to offer you any further guidance (other than strongly recommending to read something like http://learnpythonthehardway.org).

Comment: It's a `TypeError` to return anything except `None` from `__init__`.